# Why do i have error when deploying static project in github pages

Tags: github, sass, github-pages

I have deployed my project on github pages but i had this page when i opened the link in gh-pages setting  :
[image]

This is my url : https://meriemu.github.io/map-mapbox-js/
And the Github repository : https://github.com/Meriemu/map-mapbox-js

I didn't have this problem before installing sass with npm so i don"t know where is the issue.

This is my project repository too:

[image]

My package.json :

```
    {
      "homepage": "https://Meriemu.github.io/map-mapbox-js",
      "name": "map-mapbox",
      "scripts": {
        "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
        "sass": "sass scss:public",
        "sass:dev": "sass --watch --embed-source-map scss:public/styles",
        "sass:prod": "sass --no-source-map --style compressed scss:public/styles"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "gh-pages": "^4.0.0"
      },
      "version": "1.0.0",
    ..
    ....
    ..
    .
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see your page if I visit https://meriemu.github.io/map-mapbox-js/public/, which is where your `index.html` file is located.

The 404 error page explains the issue as well:

> For root URLs (like http://example.com/) you must provide an index.html file.

Comment: but the repository structure  will not be organized if itake the file out of the public folder, i will have only styles inside /public, UGLY :(

Comment: I see what you mean - maybe you could create a `css` folder at the root and put your styles there? And then you wouldn't need the `public` folder anymore